# AB Split Test Based On Click Event

Tags: content-testing

When setting up an AB split test, I know we have to set up goals on our destination pages and that can be used to determine whether the A or B is more valuable based on what the user clicked. This is used to determine the winner.

However, we have an add to cart link on our site which simply posts to an external url and shows a modal. There is no destination page. I would like to set up an AB split test on 2 pages to see which page captured more add to cart clicks. I would like to do this based on out of the box functionality, not by writing any custom code. How can I accomplish this?

I am on Sitecore 9.1, initial version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `sc_trk={GOALID}` query string if that helps. This will trigger the goal from url by the querystring.

https://www.stoneshark.se/2021/03/11/the-forgotten-goal-tracker-sc_trk/